# What is the difference between a "stanza" and a "verse", as applied to English literature?

Tags: differences, nouns, terminology, poetry, lyrics

What is the difference between 'stanza' and 'verse' in English Literature (Poetry)? I've read one of my classmate's essays and the word 'verse' cropped up - I thought that the word 'verse' was usually used for song/lyrics and was quite confused when it was used in that context (Poem analysis).

Comment: _The Norton Anthology of Poetry_ provides a good glossary of literary and poetic terms [here](http://www.wwnorton.com/college/english/nap/glossary_a.htm).

Comment: Song lyrics *are* poetry, and many poems were written as songs or in imitation of song forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I'm reading here.

> 1. A group of lines forming the basic recurring metrical unit in a poem; a verse.

The two are synonyms.

From: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stanza)

But I think the difference is that a *stanza* is more about structure, whereas a *verse* is less about rhyming scheme and more just a way to identify sections of a piece of writing.

Comment: I won't downvote your explanation but encourage you to edit your response to be more idiomatic. "Rhyme scheme" is the preferred phrase among poets. "(A) stanza" and "(a) verse" may be synonymous when they refer specifically to a unit of a poem or scripture (not sections of any piece of writing). Stanzas, which may or may not have a predetermined meter or rhyme scheme, are formal units of larger poems; they are often identified by the number of lines they contain (a Petrarchan sonnet has two stanzas: an octet and sestet); "Verse" (no article) is synonymous with the _whole_ of poetry.

Comment: @jeffclef You seem to have this down pretty well. Why don't you just type up a better answer?

Answer (score 3):

*Verse* refers any text presented over multiple lines, where the line breaks are deliberate and integral to the work itself, such as in conventional poems. This is as opposed to *prose*, which is text arranged in paragraphs, such as in a typical Wikipedia article.

Thus, *verse* can refer to any number of lines grouped together, whether it be an entire poem, or just a section of it.

*Stanza*, meanwhile, specifically refers to a formally defined unit of a poem, much like a paragraph in an essay.